# pipe to adop: stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: shell, terminal, pipe, input

```
bash-3.2$ echo "apps" | adop -status
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
Enter the APPS password: stty: standard input: Invalid argument
```

I tried like this also `stty -ixon;echo "apps" | adop -status`but same error.

Comment: What is this `adop` ?

Comment: Do you have your tty configured? What is output of ``tty``? What is your ``$TERM`` value?

Comment: @user996142 `bash-3.2$ tty /dev/pts/1 bash-3.2$ echo $TERM xterm`

Comment: @Steve adop is an Oracle EBS application script to check status.

Comment: Looks like `adop` wants standard input to be a terminal, but that is not the case because of the `echo` pipeline. Try instead `expect` or something to automate it?

Comment: @thrig, yeah expect is working fine,thought of using echo as it much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

With `expect` you can fake a terminal to `adop` and then feed it input via the `spawn` procedure:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
spawn -noecho adop -status
send "apps"
expect -ex "Enter the APPS password"
send "thepassword"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou all, I am using `echo "apps" | adop -status 2>/dev/null`, its working fine.